# Error while loading raster data in netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I am unable to load raster image into netlogo.

---

Following is the code i have used:

```
extensions [ gis ]

globals [ raster-dataset ]

to setup

  set raster-dataset gis:load-dataset "D:/SUKHJIT PROJECT/1979sup2.asc"

end
```

---

The error message displayed:

> Extension exception: only GEOGCS and PROJCS are supported
>   error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET
>   called by procedure LOAD-RASTER
>   called by Button 'Raster'

---

The image i am trying to load is an unsupervised classified raster image which i have converted in .asc format in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That NetLogo code looks fine and is exactly the same syntax that I have successfully used in my project. One possibility is that the problem is with the format of the .asc data, it may have been corrupted. Try opening the .asc dataset with a text editor and check that it looks like the example given at [ArcGIS doco](http://webhelp.esri.com/ARCGISDESKTOP/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=ESRI%20ASCII%20Raster%20format). In particular, the first 6 lines have specific information about how much GIS data follows. If nothing is obviously wrong, please provide a screenshot of the top left corner (first 6 lines plus a bit) of your .asc file in the text editor.

Comment: Thanks JenB for your help. The problem was with the projection system which was not supported by NetLogo.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is about the projection defined in the .prj file that goes along with the .asc file. The .prj file declares that your data is in a projection that isn't supported by the GIS Extension. If you don't need to combine your raster data with other GIS data, then you can just delete or rename the .prj file. If you do need to combine your data with other data, you can use ArcGIS to project the raster to a different projection before you export it to an .asc file.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I managed  to load my raster image in NetLogo with your help.